# Using Angular JS(Protractor) with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm trying to select a textarea wrapped in **angular 1** using **selenium**, but it can't be seen in DOM. There's a module called [Pytractor](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytractor). I've been trying to solve this but I'm unable to use it correctly.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can also use regular selenium bindings to test AngularJS applications. You would need to use [Explicit Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits) to wait for elements to appear, disappear, title/url to change etc - for any actions that would let you continue with testing the page.

Example (waiting for `textarea` element to appear):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "myaccount")))
```

---

There is one important  thing that `pytractor` (as `protractor` itself) provides - it knows when `AngularJS` is settled and ready - models are updated, there are no outstanding async requests etc. It doesn't mean you have to use it to test `AngularJS` applications, but it gives you an advantage.

Additionally, `pytractor` provides you with new locators, e.g. you can find an element by model or binding. It also doesn't mean you cannot find the same element using other location techniques which [regular selenium python provides out-of-the-box](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html).

Note that `pytractor` is not actively developed and maintained at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

You may just mine protractor for useful code snippets. I personally use this function that blocks until Angular is done rendering the page.

```python
def wait_for_angular(self, selenium_driver):
    selenium_driver.set_script_timeout(10)
    selenium_driver.execute_async_script("""
        callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
        angular.element('html').injector().get('$browser').notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(callback);""")
```

Replace `'html'` for whatever element is your `'ng-app'`.

Solution for Angular 1 comes from [**protractor**/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L51](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/71532f0/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L51). It could also be possible to adapt the solution to Angular 2 [using this updated code](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/a62efc6/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L143)

Comment: I have to use document.getElementsByTagName('html') for avoid the error "Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite!"

Comment: This worked for me and I like the idea of using what protractor uses too. Nice catch 