# Selenium WebDriver and generic wait or delay

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I'm desperately looking for a way to delay some executions in WebDriver but I don't seem to find one.

The web app which I try to run black box test against, works with ajax calls but these ajax calls do not render anything on DOM, thus I can't use explicit wait. Also, the implicit only works for `find_element` statements and again won't be useful.

I had success using `time.sleep()` but I hope there is a nicer way of delaying the execution.

Comment: What do these AJAX calls return? If you open the browser manually, how would you identify that the load is completed? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe, sometime they set cookies and sometime they just store variable on the `ng-controller`.

Comment: Thanks, and this is only during the page load, correct?

Comment: @alecxe, not necessarily. Think of a form that when is submitted, send an ajax call. Before response is received if you click `next`, you're doomed but after that, it'll take you where it should. And no, the button is not disabled or enabled during this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand (it's 1am here, I may miss something), you need your tests to be synchronized with AngularJS, waiting for outstanding requests and angular to "settle down".

This is what, in Javascript world, [`protractor`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/) solves perfectly - it always knows when Angular is ready and it makes the tests much more natural, you don't even think about synchronization issues - it works smoothly and out of the box:

> You no longer need to add waits and sleeps to your test. Protractor
>   can automatically execute the next step in your test the moment the
>   webpage finishes pending tasks, so you don’t have to worry about
>   waiting for your test and webpage to sync.

As for Python, there is [`pytractor`](https://github.com/kpodl/pytractor) project that sounds like something you should evaluate:

> pytractor is an extension to the Selenium bindings for Python. Its
>   goal is to make testing of angular.js applications easier with Python.
>
> It is built on some parts of protractor, the "official" Javascript
>   E2E/Scenario testing framework for Angular.js.

As a red flag, note that the project is not actively maintained. At least, you may study the source and use the ideas introduced in the code.

Note that internally `protractor` and `pytractor` inject client-side scripts which are asynchronously executed. In order to wait for Angular to be "ready", they both use `angular.getTestability(el).whenStable()` ([source](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L48)).

---

See also:

- [Understanding execute async script in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057338/understanding-execute-async-script-in-selenium)
- [Using Angular JS(Protractor) with Selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29503342/using-angular-jsprotractor-with-selenium-in-python)
- [Force Selenium to wait for AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20806399/force-selenium-to-wait-for-angularjs)

Comment: This sounds cool, but how does it do that? Does it listen to all ajax calls on the browser?

Comment: @norbertpy protractor (and pytractor) injects client side scripts. Before any action executes an async script and use `angular.getTestability(el).whenStable()` internally ([source](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L48)).

Comment: @norbertpy you can actually use `driver.execute_async_script()` and make a custom wait based on this idea.

Comment: Awesome, I'll give it a shot. Thanks.

Comment: @norbertpy added some more links. Let me know if you'll need help with the async script and a wait (I'll be afk for a rather long time but I hope I'll come back here). Good luck in solving it. Thanks.

Comment: Appreciate it. I'll dig it in. Thank you and have a good night.

Comment: `Pytractor` was abandoned. I recommend using [python selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) directly. To wait for angular I used [this solution based on protractor code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38657401/1092815) 

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).build();

driver.sleep(1000);
```