# Locating an element using ng-model using Selenium in python

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate an AngularJS application using Selenium in python. I am trying to find an element with ng-modal. I have seen some post related to Java  which specifies that you can use the following statement

```
"//input[@ng-model='yourName']"
```

I am trying to do the same in python

```
(By.XPATH, "//*/select[@ng-model='yourName']")
```

But I am unable to find the element. Am I missing something or is there is some other way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since, this is an Angular application and python-selenium does not natively wait for Angular to "settle down" (as, for instance, [`protractor`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/) or [`pytractor`](https://github.com/kpodl/pytractor)), you need to [*explicitly wait for the element to become present*](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
elm = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@ng-model='yourName']")))
```

See also:

- [Selenium WebDriver and generic wait or delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31578505/selenium-webdriver-and-generic-wait-or-delay)

Comment: Apart from EC.presence_of_element_located, sometimes the element is not yet visible to the user to be interactable, in which case it's better to use EC.visibility_of_element_located

Comment: i tried the above code but its not working. nothing happens.i tried both EC.presence and EC.presence.