# How to find some specific elements they don't have "id" in Angular code?

Tags: javascript, angular, selenium, xpath, element

This is the code of an element in a webpage written in `AngularJS`:

```html
<div class="splitter_panel" style="height: 100px;">
    <section class="layout-bottom" ng-class="{ maxWidth:hideLayoutR || hideRightMenu }">
        <div class="tabset" id="espilitBottom">
            <div class="tab-header">
                <ul class="tab-header-ul">
                    <li class="tab-header-li active" ng-click="tabSelected = 1" ng-class="{ active:tabSelected == 1 }">
                        سفارشات فعال <i class="counts ng-binding">2</i></li>
                    <li class="tab-header-li" ng-click="tabSelected =2" ng-class="{ active:tabSelected == 2 }"> خطای
                        سفارشات <i class="counts ng-binding">0</i></li>
                    <li class="tab-header-li " ng-click="tabSelected = 3" ng-class="{ active:tabSelected == 3 }"> وضعیت
                        موقعیت های باز </li>
                    <li class="tab-header-li " ng-click="tabSelected = 4" ng-class="{ active:tabSelected == 4 }">
                        معاملات امروز <i class="counts"></i></li>
                    <li class="tab-header-li" ng-click="tabSelected = 5" ng-class="{ active:tabSelected == 5 }"> وضعیت
                        حساب <i class="counts"></i></li>
                    <li class="tab-header-li " ng-click="tabSelected = 6" ng-class="{ active:tabSelected == 6 }"> سود و
                        زیان <i class="counts"></i></li>
                    <li class="tab-header-li " ng-click="tabSelected = 7" ng-class="{ active:tabSelected == 7 }"> پیش
                        بینی وضعیت <i class="counts"></i></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-body resize-bottom">
                <!-- ngIf: tabSelected==1 -->
                <!-- ngInclude: '/App/Views/Order/openOrderListInDashborad.html' -->
                <div ng-include="'/App/Views/Order/openOrderListInDashborad.html'"
                    ng-controller="OpenOrderListController" ng-if="tabSelected==1" class="maxheight ng-scope">
                    <form id="antiForgeryOrderListForm" class="maxheight ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope">
                        <div style="height:calc(100% - 41px);overflow: auto" class="w1360">
                            <table class="table-layot-bottom" show-filter="showFilter">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="orderSelection.selectAll"
                                                ng-change="selectAll(filteredOrders)"
                                                class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty"><span>ردیف</span>
                                        </th>
                                        <th ng-class="{sortAsc: reverse, sortDesc: !reverse}"
                                            ng-click="predicate='DecisionId'; reverse=!reverse" style="cursor: pointer"
                                            class="ng-scope sortDesc">شماره سفارش<span ng-show="predicate=='DecisionId'"
                                                class="ng-hide"></span></th>
                                        <th ng-class="{sortAsc: reverse, sortDesc: !reverse}"
                                            ng-click="predicate='CreationDate'; reverse=!reverse"
                                            style="cursor: pointer" class="ng-scope sortDesc">ساعت<span
                                                ng-show="predicate=='CreationDate'" class="ng-hide"></span></th>
                                        <th ng-class="{sortAsc: reverse, sortDesc: !reverse}"
                                            ng-click="predicate='ContractCode'; reverse=!reverse"
                                            style="cursor: pointer" class="ng-scope sortDesc">کد قرارداد<span
                                                ng-show="predicate=='ContractCode'" class="ng-hide"></span></th>
                                        <th ng-class="{sortAsc: reverse, sortDesc: !reverse}"
                                            ng-click="predicate='OrderSide'; reverse=!reverse" style="cursor: pointer"
                                            class="ng-scope sortDesc"> نوع سفارش<span ng-show="predicate=='OrderSide'"
                                                class="ng-hide"></span></th>
                                        <th ng-class="{sortAsc: reverse, sortDesc: !reverse}"
                                            ng-click="predicate='TradedQuantity'; reverse=!reverse"
                                            style="cursor: pointer" class="ng-scope sortDesc">حجم معامله شده<span
                                                ng-show="predicate=='TradedQuantity'" class="ng-hide"></span></th>
                                        <th ng-class="{sortAsc: reverse, sortDesc: !reverse}"
                                            ng-click="predicate='LastRemainigQuantity'; reverse=!reverse"
                                            style="cursor: pointer" class="ng-scope sortDesc"> حجم در صف <i
                                                title="جمع حجم در صف" class="counts sum ng-binding"> 0 </i><span
                                                ng-show="predicate=='LastRemainigQuantity'" class="ng-hide"></span></th>
                                        <th ng-class="{sortAsc: reverse, sortDesc: !reverse}"
                                            ng-click="predicate='Price'; reverse=!reverse" style="cursor: pointer"
                                            class="ng-scope sortDesc">قیمت<span ng-show="predicate=='Price'"
                                                class="ng-hide"></span></th>
                                        <th ng-class="{sortAsc: reverse, sortDesc: !reverse}"
                                            ng-click="predicate='DecisionUiState'; reverse=!reverse"
                                            style="cursor: pointer" class="ng-scope sortDesc">وضعیت<span
                                                ng-show="predicate=='DecisionUiState'" class="ng-hide"></span></th>
                                        <th ng-class="{sortAsc: reverse, sortDesc: !reverse}"
                                            ng-click="predicate='Channel'; reverse=!reverse" style="cursor: pointer"
                                            class="ng-scope sortDesc">درگاه ثبت<span ng-show="predicate=='Channel'"
                                                class="ng-hide"></span></th>
                                        <th colspan="2"><button type="button" class="btn refresh" tooltip-right=""
                                                tooltip="بارگذاری مجدد" ng-click="reload()"><i
                                                    class="iconRefresh"></i></button></th>
                                        <th></th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr ng-show="showFilter" class="tableFilters ng-hide">
                                        <th class="filter"></th>
                                        <th class="filter"></th>
                                        <th class="filter"><select ng-model="search.ContractCode"
                                                ng-options="c.Symbol as c.Symbol for c in symbols"
                                                class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">
                                                <option value="string:" selected="selected"></option>
                                                <option label="SAFTR98   " value="string:SAFTR98   ">SAFTR98 </option>
                                                <option label="SAFMO98   " value="string:SAFMO98   ">SAFMO98 </option>
                                                <option label="OSFTR98   " value="string:OSFTR98   ">OSFTR98 </option>
                                                <option label="OSFMO98   " value="string:OSFMO98   ">OSFMO98 </option>
                                            </select></th>
                                        <th class="filter"><select style="width:100%" ng-model="search.OrderSide"
                                                class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">
                                                <option value=""></option>
                                                <option value="0">خرید</option>
                                                <option value="1">فروش</option>
                                            </select></th>
                                        <th class="filter"><input type="text" ng-model="search.TradedQuantity"
                                                class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty"></th>
                                        <th class="filter"><input type="text" ng-model="search.LastRemainigQuantity"
                                                class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty"></th>
                                        <th class="filter"><input type="text" ng-model="search.Price"
                                                class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty"></th>
                                        <th class="filter"><select style="width:100%" ng-model="search.DecisionUiState"
                                                class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">
                                                <option value=""></option>
                                                <option value="101">ثبت شده در بورس</option>
                                                <option value="109">ثبت شده در سیستم</option>
                                                <option value="107">رد شده توسط سیستم</option>
                                                <option value="106">رد شده توسط بورس</option>
                                                <option value="112">قسمتی معامله شده</option>
                                            </select></th>
                                        <th class="filter"><select style="width:100%" ng-model="search.Channel"
                                                class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">
                                                <option value=""></option>
                                                <option value="0">آنلاین</option>
                                                <option value="1">سما</option>
                                                <option value="3">صحرا</option>
                                                <option value="4">سیستم</option>
                                            </select></th>
                                        <th class="filter"><input type="text" ng-model="search.DecisionId"
                                                class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty"></th>
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th style="width:20px!important"></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody loading-container="loading" class="ng-isolate-scope loadingContainer">
                                    <!-- ngRepeat: order in (filteredOrders = ($root.orders | orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter:search) ) -->
                                    <tr ng-repeat-start="order in (filteredOrders = ($root.orders | orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter:search) )"
                                        class="ng-scope">
                                        <td class="number ng-binding">
                                            <!-- ngIf: order.RequestState ==4 || order.InProgressRequests && order.InProgressRequests.length < 0 --><input
                                                type="checkbox" ng-model="order.Selected"
                                                ng-if="order.RequestState ==4 || order.InProgressRequests &amp;&amp; order.InProgressRequests.length < 0"
                                                class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ng-empty">
                                            <!-- end ngIf: order.RequestState ==4 || order.InProgressRequests && order.InProgressRequests.length < 0 -->
                                            1 </td>
                                        <td class="ng-binding">24277213</td>
                                        <td class="ng-binding">10:12:22</td>
                                        <td class="ng-binding">SAFMO98 </td>
                                        <td ng-class="{buy: order.OrderSide == 0, sell: order.OrderSide == 1}"
                                            class="ng-binding buy">خرید</td>
                                        <td class="ng-binding">0</td>
                                        <td class="ng-binding">1</td>
                                        <td class="ng-binding">129,900</td>
                                        <td class="actionbar ng-binding"> ثبت شده در بورس <a tooltip="مشاهده پیغام خطا"
                                                class="iconInfo ng-hide" ng-click="showErrorText(order)"
                                                ng-show="order.DecisionUiState ==107||order.DecisionUiState ==106"></a><a
                                                tooltip="درخواست در بورس تایید شد" class="Font RequestAccept"
                                                ng-show="order.DecisionUiState == 101"></a></td>
                                        <td class="ng-binding">آنلاین</td>
                                        <td class="actionbar" colspan="2"><a tooltip="نمایش نده" tooltip-left=""
                                                class="iconLogout ng-hide" ng-click="hidden(order)"
                                                ng-show="order.DecisionUiState ==107||order.DecisionUiState ==106"></a><a
                                                tooltip="ویرایش سفارش" class="iconEdit" ng-click="showEditBox(order)"
                                                ng-hide="order.RequestState !=4 || order.InProgressRequests &amp;&amp; order.InProgressRequests.length > 0"></a><a
                                                tooltip="حذف سفارش" class="iconCancel" ng-click="deleteOrder(order)"
                                                ng-hide="order.RequestState !=4 || order.InProgressRequests &amp;&amp; order.InProgressRequests.length > 0"></a>
                                            <!-- ngIf: $root.inOrderNote -->
                                        </td>
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr><!-- ngRepeat: request in order.InProgressRequests -->
                                    <!-- end ngRepeat: order in (filteredOrders = ($root.orders | orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter:search) ) -->
                                    <tr ng-repeat-start="order in (filteredOrders = ($root.orders | orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter:search) )"
                                        class="ng-scope">
                                        <td class="number ng-binding">
                                            <!-- ngIf: order.RequestState ==4 || order.InProgressRequests && order.InProgressRequests.length < 0 --><input
                                                type="checkbox" ng-model="order.Selected"
                                                ng-if="order.RequestState ==4 || order.InProgressRequests &amp;&amp; order.InProgressRequests.length < 0"
                                                class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ng-empty">
                                            <!-- end ngIf: order.RequestState ==4 || order.InProgressRequests && order.InProgressRequests.length < 0 -->
                                            2 </td>
                                        <td class="ng-binding">24277212</td>
                                        <td class="ng-binding">10:12:12</td>
                                        <td class="ng-binding">SAFMO98 </td>
                                        <td ng-class="{buy: order.OrderSide == 0, sell: order.OrderSide == 1}"
                                            class="ng-binding sell">فروش</td>
                                        <td class="ng-binding">0</td>
                                        <td class="ng-binding">1</td>
                                        <td class="ng-binding">140,000</td>
                                        <td class="actionbar ng-binding"> ثبت شده در بورس <a tooltip="مشاهده پیغام خطا"
                                                class="iconInfo ng-hide" ng-click="showErrorText(order)"
                                                ng-show="order.DecisionUiState ==107||order.DecisionUiState ==106"></a><a
                                                tooltip="درخواست در بورس تایید شد" class="Font RequestAccept"
                                                ng-show="order.DecisionUiState == 101"></a></td>
                                        <td class="ng-binding">آنلاین</td>
                                        <td class="actionbar" colspan="2"><a tooltip="نمایش نده" tooltip-left=""
                                                class="iconLogout ng-hide" ng-click="hidden(order)"
                                                ng-show="order.DecisionUiState ==107||order.DecisionUiState ==106"></a><a
                                                tooltip="ویرایش سفارش" class="iconEdit" ng-click="showEditBox(order)"
                                                ng-hide="order.RequestState !=4 || order.InProgressRequests &amp;&amp; order.InProgressRequests.length > 0"></a><a
                                                tooltip="حذف سفارش" class="iconCancel" ng-click="deleteOrder(order)"
                                                ng-hide="order.RequestState !=4 || order.InProgressRequests &amp;&amp; order.InProgressRequests.length > 0"></a>
                                            <!-- ngIf: $root.inOrderNote -->
                                        </td>
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr><!-- ngRepeat: request in order.InProgressRequests -->
                                    <!-- end ngRepeat: order in (filteredOrders = ($root.orders | orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter:search) ) -->
                                    <div ng-show="isLoading" class="loading ng-scope ng-hide"><span
                                            class="loadingPos"><span class="borderloading"></span><span
                                                class="logoLoader"></span></span></div>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="filter-part"><label class="part" ng-init="showFilter=false"><i
                                    class="Font Ico-filter" style="cursor: pointer"
                                    ng-click="showFilter=!showFilter;"></i></label><label class="part"><span> نوع سفارش:
                                </span><select ng-model="search.OrderSide"
                                    ng-options="c.id as c.title for c in orderType"
                                    class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">
                                    <option label="همه" value="string:" selected="selected">همه</option>
                                    <option label="خرید" value="number:0">خرید</option>
                                    <option label="فروش" value="number:1">فروش</option>
                                </select></label> | <label class="part"><span> سررسید: </span><select
                                    ng-model="search.ContractCode" ng-options="c.Symbol as c.Symbol for c in symbols"
                                    class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">
                                    <option value="string:" selected="selected"></option>
                                    <option label="SAFTR98   " value="string:SAFTR98   ">SAFTR98 </option>
                                    <option label="SAFMO98   " value="string:SAFMO98   ">SAFMO98 </option>
                                    <option label="OSFTR98   " value="string:OSFTR98   ">OSFTR98 </option>
                                    <option label="OSFMO98   " value="string:OSFMO98   ">OSFMO98 </option>
                                </select></label> | <label class="part">
                                <!-- ngIf: selectedOrdersNumber() --></label></div>
                    </form>
                </div><!-- end ngIf: tabSelected==1 -->
                <!-- ngIf: tabSelected == 2 -->
                <!-- ngIf: tabSelected == 3 -->
                <!-- ngIf: tabSelected == 4 -->
                <!-- ngIf: tabSelected == 5 -->
                <!-- ngIf: tabSelected == 6 -->
                <!-- ngIf: tabSelected == 7 -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

And the following code is my python code using Selenium to find some other elements of the page (`price_tir` , `price_mordad`):

```js
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
driver.get("https://onlineime.agah.com")
driver.refresh()

time.sleep(45)
login = driver.find_element_by_id("submit-btn")
login.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.refresh()

driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
price_tir = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'SAFTR98')]/ancestor::fieldset//input[@ng-model='item.Price']")
price_mordad = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'SAFMO98')]/ancestor::fieldset//input[@ng-model='item.Price']")
```

What I want to do is addressing the following parts of code from the above element to my python program, like what I did for `price_tir` and `price_mordad` elements in last lines of the above python code:

```html
                                        <td class="ng-binding">SAFMO98 </td>
                                        <td ng-class="{buy: order.OrderSide == 0, sell: order.OrderSide == 1}"
                                            class="ng-binding buy">خرید</td>
                                        <td class="ng-binding">0</td>
                                        <td class="ng-binding">1</td>
                                        <td class="ng-binding">129,900</td>
                                        <td class="actionbar ng-binding"> ثبت شده در بورس <a tooltip="مشاهده پیغام خطا"
                                                class="iconInfo ng-hide" ng-click="showErrorText(order)"
                                                ng-show="order.DecisionUiState ==107||order.DecisionUiState ==106"></a><a
                                                tooltip="درخواست در بورس تایید شد" class="Font RequestAccept"
                                                ng-show="order.DecisionUiState == 101"></a></td>
                                        <td class="ng-binding">آنلاین</td>
```

And:

```html
                                        <td class="ng-binding">SAFMO98 </td>
                                        <td ng-class="{buy: order.OrderSide == 0, sell: order.OrderSide == 1}"
                                            class="ng-binding sell">فروش</td>
                                        <td class="ng-binding">0</td>
                                        <td class="ng-binding">1</td>
                                        <td class="ng-binding">140,000</td>
                                        <td class="actionbar ng-binding"> ثبت شده در بورس <a tooltip="مشاهده پیغام خطا"
                                                class="iconInfo ng-hide" ng-click="showErrorText(order)"
                                                ng-show="order.DecisionUiState ==107||order.DecisionUiState ==106"></a><a
                                                tooltip="درخواست در بورس تایید شد" class="Font RequestAccept"
                                                ng-show="order.DecisionUiState == 101"></a></td>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195753/discussion-on-question-by-hasani-how-to-find-an-element-that-seems-only-works-in).

Comment: @SaurabhGaur, may you read the edit part and help me to find this list element to read and modify it's values?