# Webdriver&Python: Using time.sleep() to test Angular2 App

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests

I've got a question about using time.sleep() to test Angular2 app. I do know that there is something like Protractor (and Pytractor) and you can use it when writing functional tests in Selenium. You can also use Explicit Waits. I found this info e.g. here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29503381/6401796
But what about using time import? Is that even correct to write tests like that for Angular2 apps?
My code:

```
import time
def open_login_page(self):
    wd = self.wd
    wd.get(localhost)
    time.sleep(10)
```

I'm waiting here for all elements to show up. Thank you for considering my request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "someID")))
```

Explicit wait is waiting for the condition to met **up** to the specified time, 10 seconds in this example. If the element is visible after 2 seconds the script will continue after 2 seconds of waiting.

When using

```
time.sleep(10)
```

The script will wait for 10 seconds no matter what, unnecessary 8 seconds delay.